# Echo inside the html tag

Tags: php

The PHP only works on echoing the content when I echo it directly with the HTML tag (`echo` is outside the tag), as follows

```
include('db.php');
$blogurl="http://www.com/view/";
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
echo "<h2><a href=" . $blogurl . $row['url'] . ">" . $row['title'] . "</a></h2>";
```

}

But it doesn't work when I try with this style:

```
<?php
    include('db.php');
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY `id` ASC");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
        $blogurl="http://www.com/view";
        $url=$row['url'];
        $title=$row['title'];
?>
        <td>
            <a href="<?php echo $blogurl;?>/<?php echo $url;?>"><?php echo $title;?></a>   
        </td>
<?php
    }
?>
```

What I want is to change the way I echo the data from the database. But what is wrong with that second style?

Comment: -1 for such a question

Comment: missing semicolon in the code. You can use http://phpcodechecker.com/ for syntax error checking...

Comment: Please post generated HTML. Are you using a valid html?

Comment: what i meant is you should learn to debug your code!! logical errors, bad practice.. are a different thing!! why should others fix your syntax errors and typos :)
for example mixing the views codes and database model) codes is not a good thing!, you end up with repetitive , unmaintable codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved it. I think the problem is because we can't get the content which has an extension of html from database. So the solution is I have to create a string or a var or (I dont know what we call it in php) by as follows:

`<?php echo $blogurl;?>/<?php echo $title.".html"?>`

The solution is that I don't need the row of url in my database. I just need to echo the title and give the ".html" behind it.

Thanks for anyone who has tried to helped me.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Code should be:

```
<?php
            include('db.php');
            $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY `id` ASC");
            $blogurl="http://www.com/view";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
                       $url=$row['url'];
            ?>

        <td><a href="<?php echo $blogurl;?>/<?php echo $url;?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a></td>


            <?php
             }
            ?>
```

Comment: it doesn't work. the only thing I aware is that the problem is come from the <?php echo $url;? it doesn't get the row from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <?php
    include('db.php');
    $blogurl="http://www.com/view";
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo "<h2><a href='" . $blogurl."/".$row['url']  . "'>" . $row['title'] . "</a></h2>";
}
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
     <?php
        include('db.php');
        $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY `id` ASC");
        $blogurl="http://www.com/view";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {

        $url=$row['url'];
        $title=$row['title'];
        ?>

    <td><a href="<?php echo $blogurl.'/'. $url;?>"><?= $title;?></a></td>


        <?php
         }
        ?>
```